# Ctrl-C doesn't quit program when using sytem() in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this program:

```
5.times do |i|
  puts "Iteration #{i}"
  system("sleep 3")
end
```

I want to exit this program after, say 2 iterations, usin `Ctrl-C`

If I hit `Ctrl-C`, this happens:

```
➜  tmp  ruby system.rb 
Iteration 0
^CIteration 1
^CIteration 2
^CIteration 3
^CIteration 4
^C%
```

The `system()` command is run 5 times, no matter what.

What can I do so that I'm able to quit the execution using `Ctrl-C`?

Comment: In my environment, the script stops immediately.  I use `ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-linux]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Kernel#system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system) executes a given command in a sub-shell. Which means that Ctrl-C is going to that subshell and not your ruby script, so there's no use trapping it there. However, the command returns a value which indicates, whether it was completed successfully or not. When the command is stopped via Ctrl-C, it won't count as a successful completion. So, check the return value.

```
5.times do |i|
  puts "Iteration #{i}"
  success = system("sleep 3")
  break unless success
end
```

Comment: Good answer, but unless I'm missing something, just use `sleep 3` instead of `system("sleep 3")`

Comment: @pguardiario: I guess, it is just a placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

Since the program invoked by the `system` command get the interrupt, the program (in this case, `sleep`) quit. But the ruby interpreter do not receive the interrupt, it won't quit.

But if you check the return value of the `system` method call, you can detect the value of exit code of the program you're invoking. Thus following code works.

```
5.times do |i|
  puts "Iteration #{i}"
  unless system("sleep 3")
    puts "Got an interupt?"
    exit 0
  end
end
```

Check the [system method reference in Module: Kernel](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system).